# iPhone: InterfaceBuilder nibs disconnected from my project

Tags: iphone

Since upgrading to XCode 3.2, InterfaceBuilder doesn't play nice. All of my image links are broken in IB but they'll show fine when I compile. When I go to the combo box to select an image for my UIImageView, it doesn't have the image files I've added to my app.

I also can't create a new .nib and associate it with a class I've written. Like images, my custom viewcontrollers aren't available to pick from.

I'm going to try a reinstall but I was curious if anyone's dealt with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up trying to fix and resorted the classic workaround. Started a clean project and schlepped everything over. Things are fine...for now.

Comment: ...but 24 hours later here we are again. Very annoying.